# Mousevover Popup Delay - Elementor Popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a webpage is a link. When you hover over the link with the mouse, it displays a popup of another webpage. I have to delay the popup because right now it pops up too quickly on mouseover. ALso I need to stop opening the popup if the mouse moves off the link before the popup opens.

I have tried to add the setTimeout function to the code, but I do not know where to put it. Wherever I try to put it, the popup stops working, Ive tried to put setTimeout(function(){ CODE }, 1000; around the second part of the code but it it doesnt work.

**Here is the code below:**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.popupgg' );
let popupposts = ['3525'];

elements.forEach(function(e,i){
e.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function(){
elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
} );
});
});
</script>
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see my working example, here I'm triggering an alert after one second and half. I've just commented the line `//elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );` since I have no access to the function `elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup()` but I'm making it work just using an `alert()` function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1 class="popupgg">My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>


  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.popupgg' );
      let popupposts = ['3525'];
      
      elements.forEach(function(e,i) {
        let pupup_timeout; //create a vriable to store the timeout reference
        e.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function() {
          pupup_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            alert('This alert is showed after 1500 millisecons, one second and half');
            //elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
          }, 1500);
        });
        
        e.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
          clearTimeout(pupup_timeout); // clear the timeout on mouse out element
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution works! Is there a way to stop opening the popup if the mouse moves off the link before the popup opens? I may need to open another question but if you could answer, that would be very helpful

Comment: Yes @JoelBeale im editing your question and rewriting my code to enable this feature

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out with that code! The html code works! At first it was not working and then after some time I was finally able to get it to work in Elementor. I changed the 'mouseout' to 'mouseleave' in the code and it started working! (and of course I removed the </html> , <head> , </body> and extra text that you had in there.