# Mouseleave link, reset timer and do not open popup - Elementor Popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a webpage is a link. When you hover over the link with the mouse, it displays a popup of another webpage after a time delay. Is there a way to stop the popup from opening and reset the timeout if the mouseover the link is moved off of the link before the popup opens?

**Below is the code I've tried but doesnt work**

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.districtmarketgg' );
      let popupposts = ['3525'];
  
      elements.forEach(function(e,i){
        e.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function(){
          setTimeout(function() {
            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
          }, 2000);
      elements.forEach(function(e,i){
        e.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function(){
          clearTimeout(function() {
            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
          });
        })  
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks for your help.

I expected for the code to work but it didnt after I added the mouseleave lines of code. I've tried to add a clearTimeout function on mouseleave to the code but the code stops working after I add those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) takes a reference to the timer's ID that you want to clear, not a function to execute.

You also don't need to loop over the collection twice. You can set both event handlers within one loop.

If you place the following `script` just prior to the closing `body` tag, you won't need the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler at all.

See comments inline below:

```
<body>
  <!-- all page HTML here -->
<script>
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.districtmarketgg' );
  let popupposts = ['3525'];
  
  // Only 1 loop is needed here
  elements.forEach(function(e,i){
    let timer = null; // Need a variable to hold a reference to the timer
  
    e.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function(){
      // Create the timer reference
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
      }, 2000);
    });
    
    // Same loop, new event handler
    e.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);  // Stop the timer
    });
  })  
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the code Scott Marcus! Someone did execute this with a slightly different code too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74869566/mousevover-popup-delay-elementor-popup I will use both codes. Thanks for the help everyone.